# postgres: Cannot use to_tsvector on a column named 'text'

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 11.5 and try to do the following:

```
update ccnc set fulltext_tokens = to_tsvector(title || '. ' || description || '. ' || text ) where fulltext_tokens is NULL;
```

Which results in

```
ERROR:  column " text" does not exist
LINE 1: ...o_tsvector(title || '. ' || description || '. ' || text ) wh...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "ccnc.text".
```

However, neither does using ccnc.text help:

```
felix=# update ccnc set fulltext_tokens = to_tsvector(title || '. ' || description || '. ' || ccnc.text) where fulltext_tokens is NULL;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table " ccnc"
LINE 1: ...o_tsvector(title || '. ' || description || '. ' || ccnc.text...
```

... nor is something odd with the respective column (no trailing spaces or the like):

```
felix=# \d+ ccnc
                                                               Table "public.ccnc"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id              | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('ccnc_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 description     | text                        |           |          | ''::text                         | extended |              |
 text            | text                        |           |          |                                  | extended |              |
 title           | text                        |           |          |                                  | extended |              |
```

Edit: 
Also quoting does not help, e.g.:

```
update ccnc set fulltext =  title || '. ' || description || '. ' || "text";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""text""
LINE 1: ... fulltext =  title || '. ' || description || '. ' || "text";
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help on how to create that new column named fulltext_tokens. Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Top tip. Your life will be much simpler if you don't name your columns and tables the same as built-in types and keywords. Until them try quoting it like "text".

Comment: Quoting does not help unfortunately, too.

Comment: I don't know, works for me.  But your table definition doesn't include a column named fulltext_tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the very valuable comment by Richard, i.e., not using a column name such as "text" in the first place, one way to avoid the error is to use `concat` or `concat_ws` instead of the concat operator `||`.

For instance:

```
update ccnc set fulltext = concat_ws('. ', title, description, text)
```